# Wordpress/Yoast: _yoast_wpseo_title/metadesc on taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, yoast

I would like to make some bulk edits on the above field for the taxonomies on my site. However after having examined in detail all the tables and field, I have been unable to find them for the taxonomies.

I have the table wp_termmeta EMPTY, and I tried to add the above fields on the table but it did not work.

Any ideas about how can I make those bulk edits for the field _yoast_wpseo_title/_yoast_wpseo_metadesc for a taxonomy?

Thanks,

Oscar